# torch.cuda.is_available() returning false with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: anaconda, pytorch, ubuntu-16.04, nvidia

I have the following configurations

- nvcc -V

> ```
> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
> Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
> Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
> Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
> ```

- nvidia-smi

[image]

- CUDA Toolkit (from Anaconda)

> cudatoolkit               10.2.89              hfd86e86_1    anaconda

- PyTorch (from Anaconda)

> pytorch                   1.5.0          py3.7_cuda10.2.89_cudnn7.6.5_0    pytorch

But I am getting `torch.cuda.is_available() -> False`

Could anyone please tell which component should I upgrade or downgrade in order to bring up the CUDA?

Comment: Your driver only supports up to cuda 10.0 (the top right corner of nvidia-smi). You need the upgrade the graphics driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 with anaconda installation, recommended from the PyTorch official website. After installing cudatoolkit 10.1 rather than recommended 10.2 I got 'True'. Some people remedied this using driver version downgrade/upgrade as this is most likely a compatibility issue.